# What's the etymology of "put feature"?

Tags: terminology

Gill, Madura. [*Personal Finance*, 4th Canadian Edition 2019](https://www.amazon.ca/Personal-Finance-Canadian-Pearson-Package/dp/013485201X/ref=pd_cp_14_1?pd_rd_w=c29n6&pf_rd_p=64a84aa4-b549-4445-9bf3-48bdeed5f24a&pf_rd_r=82BZKGBE1YW3BZXRTA41&pd_rd_r=ac94fdf8-0331-4f63-9fd4-08392967896d&pd_rd_wg=LkHyc&pd_rd_i=013485201X&psc=1&refRID=82BZKGBE1YW3BZXRTA41). p 358.

[image]

I don't know if "put" here is related to [put options](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/480876/50720).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it refers to a put option. It is like buying an ordinary put on a bond, giving you (the investor) the right to sell at a fixed price (here, face value) by a given date (here, maturity).

Bonus fact: A callable bond, similarly, is one for which the investor has effectively *written* a *call* option, giving the borrower the right to buy back the bond at a fixed price. This option is likely to be exercised if interest rates *fall*.